# In 'Little Raiders: Robin's Revenge', does the Wanted Meter impact story mission difficulty?

Tags: ios, little-raiders

Obviously the Wanted Meter increases the difficulty of available raids, but does it impact story mission difficulty? Does it increase the difficulty within a given raid?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of the in-game tips is "As Wanted Level increases, missions and enemy difficulty increase".

I have confirmed that at a high streak, towers shoot further and enemies are more difficult in random raids. I also confirmed that this is NOT the case in story missions.